# how to automatically add default columns to all django model tables

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following 4 columns which I would like to add to all tables:

- *creationname*
- *creationdate*
- *revisionname*
- *revisiondate*

currently I do it the following way:

```
from django.db import models


class Table_1(models.Model):
    column1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    column2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField('creation date', auto_now_add=False)
    revisionname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    revisiondate = models.DateTimeField('revision date', auto_now=False)

class Table_2(models.Model):
    column1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    column2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField('creation date', auto_now_add=False)
    revisionname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    revisiondate = models.DateTimeField('revision date', auto_now=False)

...

class Table_n(models.Model):
    column1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    column2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField('creation date', auto_now_add=False)
    revisionname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    revisiondate = models.DateTimeField('revision date', auto_now=False)
```

can this be acchieved in an automated way, so the 4 columns are automatically appended to each table?
note: is this also achievable for all tables of a django project not just the tables of a single django app?

in case this is against django design philosophy please let me know as well

Comment: You could use [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [abstract base model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and inheritance to do so:

```
class ModelWithRevisions(models.Model):
    creationname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField('creation date', auto_now_add=False)
    revisionname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    revisiondate = models.DateTimeField('revision date', auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class OtherModel(ModelWithRevisions):
    column1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    column2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

---

Note that if you're trying to track the history of your models, or track who changed them last, you might want to [look into an existing model auditing package](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/).

Comment: thanks for the auditing reference as well. with a first look they appear to be oriented to data model changes. correct?  <br />note: I intend to use the creation/revision fields for the application data, e.g. when someone changes data (not data model) due to standard application behaviour.  <br />would you place this type of general data model extension which should effect all tabels in the project directory (same level as settings.py file), e.g. as models.py and inherit from there?

Comment: @udo No, the packages listed in the link I sent you care about changes to the data, *not* about changes to the data model. They seem to be what you're after. If you nonetheless opt to use the code I provided above, I encourage you to put it in a separate *app*.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to define the db column sequence when defining the model? apparently django applies the following logic when it comes to column sequence: PKs, model extensions, other fields... always in the order they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Create a base model. Then extend that model.

```
class BaseTable(models.Model):
    creationname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField('creation date', auto_now_add=True)
    revisionname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    revisiondate = models.DateTimeField('revision date', auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Table1(BaseTable):
     column1 = models.TextField()
     column2 = models.TextField()
```